# I need to change the first sentence only bold from paragraph using javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

> **Mr. MMM and Mrs. sss they are honest.** They have their own car.

Here I want to change the first sentence to bold,

> **We have a great leader F.Rah.** He is a talented boy.

Here I want to change the first sentence to bold,

> **We have a great leader F.Rah.**

Here I want to change the sentence to bold.

Comment: use a regular expression to find . space cap letter to find index of end of sentence or use a span as suggested

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = $('.last_wfp').text();
var b = a.slice(0, a.indexOf('. '));
var c = a.slice(a.indexOf('. '), a.length);

$('.last_wfp').html('<span class="last_bold">' + b + '</span>' + c);

var a = $('.last_wfp1').text();
var b = a.slice(0, a.indexOf('. '));
var c = a.slice(a.indexOf('. '), a.length);


$('.last_wfp1').html('<span class="last_bold">' + b + '</span>' + c);


var a = $('.last_wfp2').text();
var b = a.slice(0, a.indexOf('. '));
var c = a.slice(a.indexOf('. '), a.length);


$('.last_wfp2').html('<span class="last_bold">' + b + '</span>' + c);
```

```css
.last_bold{
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:2em;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="last_wfp">This is the first sentence that I want bold. This is the second sentence that I don't want that treatment. This text is lost! And then there was more.  And another sentence...</p>
<p class="last_wfp1">This is the second sentence that I want bold . This is the second sentence that I don't want that treatment. This text is lost! And then there was more.  And another sentence...</p>
<p class="last_wfp2">This is the third sentence that I want bold.</p>
```

Comment: I updated the code. Please check

Comment: I'm not well versed in JQuery but couldn't you have looped over the paragraphs with a `each` function rathe rthan write 3 separate ones?

Comment: True. But, the person whoever asked this question, i think he is beginner. So he has to learn from basic. We should not provide the advanced code to the beginners. I feel that way, so i have given that. Once he learns more, he has to loop and do the operations

Comment: Mr. MMM and Mrs. sss they are honest. They have their own car.  This sentence is not supporting.

Comment: @Ravi There is no real way to define a "sentence" in JS or CSS. You can only search for a `period` followed by a space, If you have that else where (as you suggest) then this becomes impossible to achieve programatically except by changing your HTML to add the `span` manually.

Answer (score -3):

```css
    p::first-line {
      font-weight:bold;
    }
```

```html
<p>Mr. MMM and Mrs. sss they are honest. They have own car.<p>
<p>We have a great leader F.Rah. He is a talented boy.</p>
<p>We have a great leader F.Rah</p>
```

Will do the trick for you!

Comment: Yes, I used this but when changed my screen as responsive my content lossed bold

Comment: No...it won't, this changes the whole first line **not the first sentence**. I suggest you *re-read* the question.